# cohomology vs homology

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have learned the basic things about cohomology and homology. It seems that homology and cohomology both deal with the same objects, the complexes, but with a different choice of the indexes  (for the homology the indexes are decreasing and in cohomology are increasing).

Why, in some geometric applications it is done a radical selection and it is important to distinguish homology from cohomology?

For example if one constructs a Cech homology instead af Cech cohomology, what are the differences?

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20877/what-is-the-difference-between-homology-and-cohomology .

Answer (score 14):

One short answer is that cohomology (of spaces, not of general chain complexes) carries a ring structure, the [cup product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product). There are spaces with the same homology and cohomology as groups, but where the ring structure on the cohomologies is different; in this case one can use the cup product to distinguish them.

There is probably a lot one can say as far as a long answer. For example, for nice spaces cohomology is representable by [Eilenberg-MacLane spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space), so one can say a lot about cohomology by studying these spaces (e.g. classifying [cohomology operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_operation) using the [Yoneda lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma)), and analogous things don't seem to be true of homology.

Comment: so we have this graded ring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_ring which doesn't exist for homology.

Comment: In nice situations (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/415/does-homology-have-a-coproduct) homology admits a dual structure called a comultiplication, but comultiplications are a little less intuitive to work with.